# PHP echo in Javascript variable to dynamically change pie chart diagram

Tags: php, javascript, pie-chart

I have the following code. Please look at the [jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/2w4YC/1/). In this code there are static numbers, 5 and 10. These need to be changed to dynamic numbers, produced by PHP code in variables `$result1` and `$result2`.

I have tried numerous things, see the jsfiddle page please.

So basically how to replace the 5 and 10 with PHP code in the example below?

```
var pie = new RGraph.Pie('cvs', [result1,10]);
```

The solution thanks to Jeff Shaver with help from Clamidity:

```
var pie = new RGraph.Pie('cvs', [<?php echo $result1; ?>,<?php echo $result2; ?>]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to echo them in.

```
var pie = new RGraph.Pie('cvs', [<?php echo $result1; ?>,10]);
```

Comment: Great answer. For the sake of not relying on php shortags I would use <?php echo $result1; ?>

Comment: Yes that is the answer brilliant. Thank you very much saved me a lot of time. This will be the accepted answer but i have to wait 11 minutes for that.

Comment: Or <?= $result1 ?>, which is (oddly) enabled by turning on short tags, but not deprecated along with short tags.

Comment: Just forgot to add the `php`. I have updated the answer. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Thanks for updating the code Jeff. Clamidity thanks for the php adding part!